# How to lift up DatePicker(@mui) value to a parent component?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, components, parent-child

I've just started to study ReactJS and want to write a simple app with DatePicker. My idea is to create a component, called, **DateTimeSelector** (**Child component**), with DatePicker, and to call **DateTimeSelector** in App.js (**Parent component**) multiple times (at least, to specify start and end date).

And I'm stuck at lifting up state from child to parent component.

Here is my code:

**1) DateTimeSelector (Child) component**

```
...

export default function DateTimeSelector(props) {

    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

    function onChangeHandler(newValue) {
        setValue(newValue);
        console.log(newValue);
    }

    return (
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <DatePicker label={props.text}
          value={value}
          onChange={onChangeHandler}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    );

}
```

**2) Main (Parent) component**

Within this component I want to output values of each DateTimeSelector component in console and, for example, print these values in .

Now in console I see only values from my **DateTimeSelector** component, but not from the parent.

So, my question is how to pass date values from DatePickers to parent component as the state variables: startDate and endDate?

```
...

function App() {

  const [startDate, setStartDate] = React.useState(null);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = React.useState(null);

  function startDateChangeHandler(value) {
      setStartDate(value);
      console.log(startDate);
  }

  function endDateChangeHandler(value) {
      setEndDate(value);
      console.log(endDate);
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={3}>
        <div>
          <DateTimeSelector text='Start Date' 
                            value={startDate}
                            onChange={startDateChangeHandler} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <DateTimeSelector text='End Date'
                            value={endDate}
                            onChange={endDateChangeHandler}/>
        </div>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={9}>
        <div><p>Start Date: {startDate ?  JSON.stringify(startDate) : null}</p>
             <p>End Date: {endDate ?  JSON.stringify(endDate) : null}</p>
        </div>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
     </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! Thanks for the advise not to have state in Child!

DateTimeSelector (Child)

```
export default function DateTimeSelector(props) {

    function onChangeHandler(date) {
        props.onChange(date);
    }

    return (
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <DatePicker label={props.text}
          value={props.date}
          onChange={onChangeHandler}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    );

}
```

App (Parent)

```
function App() {

  const [startDate, setStartDate] = React.useState(null);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = React.useState(null);
  
  function startDateChangeHandler(date) {
      console.log('startDateChangeHandler');
      setStartDate(date);
      console.log(startDate);
  }

  function endDateChangeHandler(date) {
    console.log('endDateChangeHandler');
    setStartDate(date);
    console.log(endDate);
}

  return (
    <Container>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={3}>
        <div>
          <DateTimeSelector text='Start Date' 
                            date={startDate}
                            onChange={startDateChangeHandler} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <DateTimeSelector text='End Date'
                            date={endDate}
                            onChange={endDateChangeHandler}/>
        </div>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={9}>
        <div>
          <p id='start_date'>Start Date: {startDate ?  JSON.stringify(startDate) : null}</p>
          <p id='end_date'>End Date: {endDate ?  JSON.stringify(endDate) : null}</p>
        </div>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
     
     <Button variant="contained">Hello World!</Button>
     </Container>
  );
}
```